# How can I have background photos changing in iOS 7 and Xcode 5 application?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a bunch of images and I need to slowly keep showing them one after another in an app that I am developing in iOS 7 using Xcode 5.

The images cover the complete screen and it is the first screen of the app. The first screen has a "Log in using Facebook" button, but at the background I want these multiple images to show up, dim and vanish, and then followed by the next image like a show of images at the background.

What is the component / controller to use for this capability?

I have this code that does not run.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:imageView duration:0.3 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut) animations:^{
        UIImage *nextImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"];
        imageView.image = nextImage;
        nextImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"];
    } completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a timer (`NSTimer`), that, every few seconds, performs the transition. I assume you display your images in a `UIImageView`.

You can accomplish this by:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:imageView duration:0.3 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut) animations:^{
        imageView.image = nextImage;
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but can you let me know how does nextImage fit within all this?

Comment: Next image is the image you want to transition to.

Comment: Thanks. So I have this code that fails to run. Edited the question above.

Comment: Got it, it looks like I need to have a NSTimer :) which I did not do.

Comment: Yes, the timer will give you what you need.